# How to set env.development and env.production in Preact app

Tags: preact

On react app, you can create .env.production and .env.development and enter different key and values like this.

`REACT_APP_API_URL= "xyz"`

to pick environment variables automatically based on commands used --> `npm start` or `npm run build`.

What is the equivalent process in preact?

Comment: React and Preact are just UI libraries. How you set env vars depends upon which build tool you're using. Can't answer without that information.

Comment: @rschristian I'm using webpack.

Comment: Then it's just standard Node behavior. It won't pick up on either of those files. You'd need to handle that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It is my solution

**env.js** in the root of project:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

function getAppEnvironment() {
    const prefix = "PREACT";
    return Object.keys(process.env)
        .filter((key) => new RegExp(`^${prefix}_`, 'i').test(key))
        .reduce((env, key) => {
            env[key] = process.env[key];
            return env;
        }, {});
}

function resolveFile(file) {
    const path = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
    return `${path}/${file}`;
}

function getEnvFiles(production) {
    const key = production ? 'production' : 'development';
    return [
        resolveFile(".env"),
        resolveFile(".env.local"),
        resolveFile(`.env.${key}`),
        resolveFile(`.env.${key}.local`),
    ].filter(Boolean);
}


export function getEnvironment(production) {
  const dotenvFiles = getEnvFiles(production);
  dotenvFiles.forEach((dotenvFile) => {
    if (fs.existsSync(dotenvFile)) {
            dotenv.config({
                path: dotenvFile,
                override: true
            })
    }
  });
  return getAppEnvironment();
}

export default getEnvironment;
```

then create or modify your **preact.config.js**:

```js
import getEnvironment from './env';

export default {
  plugins: [],
  webpack(config, env, helpers) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new helpers.webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(getEnvironment(env.production))
      }),
    );
  },
};
```